# length of infinite(unbounded) interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

i 'm studying with the book, Measure theory and Integration , G.de.Barra.

while proving the Theorem ,"The outer measure of an interval equals its length",  i have to classify the interval into bounded and unbounded.

but i don't know what exactly the length of unbounded interval is.

what is the length of the infinite(unbounded) interval?

i know the length of the bounded interval

for example, [a,b] = b-a

but i don't know (-infinite, a) (where a is just a constant) or (a, infinite)

like these guys..

and are the length of [a,b] and (a,b] are equal?

now i'm studying measure theory and little confused with these concepts.

Comment: Outer measure preserves order in the sense that if $A \subset B$ then $\mu^* A \le \mu^* B$, hence an unbounded interval (which contains intervals of arbitrary length) must have infinite length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of $[a,b]$ and $[a,b[$ are equal since $[a,b] = [a,b[ \cup \{b\}$, and the singleton $\{b\}$ has $0$ Lebesgue measure.

The Lebesgue measure of an unbounded interval is infinite. To show this, observe that $[0,a] \subseteq [0,\infty[$ for any $a > 0$. By subadditivity $a = \lambda([0,a]) \leq \lambda([0,\infty[)$. Since it holds for all $a > 0$, $\lambda([0,\infty[) = \infty$